# Current-rule's name in Snakemake

Tags: python, python-3.x, snakemake

I am working with Snakemake and I can't find a way to access to the **current-rule's name**.

For instance, is there a way to have an access like this:

```
rule job1:
    input: check_inputs(rules.current.name)
    output: ...
```

This can be very helpful when the `check_inputs` function is more or less the same for each rules.

For sure, I made this and it works:

```
rule job1:
    input: check_inputs("job1")
    output: ...
```

However, I was wondering that if a more "Snakemaker way" to get the current-rule's name exists to avoid writing / hardcoding the rule's name each time.

Any kind of help or suggestion will be highly appreciated.

**--- EDIT1 ---**
The rule name is accessible via `{rules.myrule.name}` only when the `input` and `output` statements are parsed by snakemake. So the use of `{rules.myrule.name}` is not possible in `input`/`output` definition.

The idea is to have a quick access to the current rule's name `{rules.current}` for instance, because `{rules.myrule.name}` is also repetitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Edit: Proposed a workaround)

`{rule}`can be used for rulename during shell:/run: directives. As op stated, this does not work in `input/output:`. However the current template is a work-araound

```
myrule = "foo"
rule foo:
    output: touch(myrule + ".ok")
    shell:
        'echo "I am {rule}, making {output}"'
```

In the example above, introducing the variable `myrule` is unnecessary since it is used only once. But it makes more sense when you want to use the rule-name several times in the various snakemake directives. And it also facilitates rule-templating.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround @gutorm. This feature would be so nice to have for the `log` parameter...

Answer (score 1):

I thought `rule.name` should work, but it looks like it's just `rule`, which however can't be used in all contexts: See https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/issues/199/rule-name-cant-be-accessed-by-rule-in

Andreas

Comment: Thank you for your answer. No, it's not working. rule.name is defined when input and output are parsed by snakemake. I have checked the Rules object (which contains all the rules and their attributes) and it appears only after output definition. But thank you for the issue you linked, I will create a new one for this. Except if one other person found a trick for that.

Comment: Was just coming across exactly this problem. It's still not possible to access the rule name before the run/shell block. Now there's an issue on Github tracking it: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/156